# Having issue with node-gyp and python

Tags: python, electron, node-gyp

I keep on getting this following error when I'm trying to compile my npm electron project.

I feel theres some error with node-gyp and python.

[image]

Can you guys please help me with this. How can I fix this issue?

Do I need to try to install a different version of python or something? My current python version installed is v3.9.6.

OS: Mac Latest

Comment: What happens when you type `python` in your terminal? If that doesn't work does `python3` work?

Comment: yes "python3" works. Just "python" doenst. If I go python3 --version I get "Python 3.9.6"

Comment: Was this resolved with the answer provided?

Comment: No it didn't really work. I know its a tough ask but do you think you can help me on zoom? You can send me a hi email on npat759@gmail.com I will reply.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that `node-gyp` is looking for `python` and **not** `python3`. One way to fix this is to add a `symlink`. First you want to check where `python3` is installed:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

Let us say that our version of `python3` in installed in `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Now we can create a `symlink`:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

You will have to reload your current terminal shell to use the new symlink in that shell. Run this command to reload your shell:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

Afterwards, we can verify that it is working:

```
python --version
```

Should return:

```
Python 3.9.6
```

After that, you can try your `node-gyp` command again.

Comment: I did this but still not working.

If I run 

"which python"

I get 

"python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3"

That seems to be correct as it's aliased now. But still the same error even after restarting the terminal.

Comment: That's strange. Do you get exactly the same error?

Comment: Yeah it was exactly the same error. Do you know anything else I could try?